# Using Feign Client calling 3rd party API throwing Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I am calling 3rd party search api using Feign client.Below is my code to call the 3rd party URL:

```
@FeignClient(url="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs", name="GIPHY-CLIENT")
public interface GipherSearch {
    @GetMapping("/search?api_key=QPayNCt8xoMomlYfVdySXOEGxAxXfiV2&q=cheeseburgers&limit=5")
     public List<DataModel> getData();
}
```

In my main class I just added @EnableFeignClients annotation.

```
public class GipherManagerApplication {
    @Autowired
    private GipherSearch gipherSearch;


    public GipherManagerApplication(GipherSearch gipherSearch) {
        this.gipherSearch=gipherSearch;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @GetMapping("/findAllGipher")
    public List<DataModel> getAllGipher(){
        return gipherSearch.getData();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GipherManagerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I ran the application I am getting the below exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1343) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1139) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1093) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:332) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:265) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3084) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:239) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder.decode(SpringDecoder.java:59) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:62) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:36) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:176) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:140) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy109.getData(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.stackroute.giphermanager.GipherManagerApplication.getAllGipher(GipherManagerApplication.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

To resolve the exception I am going through the below url and did the required changed. But still not getting the actual results.

```
https://reflectoring.io/accessing-spring-data-rest-with-feign/
```

Please let me know where I am doing the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`MismatchedInputException` means you are getting a wrong response body which is tried to be parsed by Jackson, let's say an object JSON `{...}` but you should receive an array of JSON objects `[{...}]`, then try to check what is the response when you get on that searching and compare if your response is `List<DataModel>` if `DataModel` contains all fields needed, also when you have `request params` like `api_key`, `q` and `limit` then you should implement by following way:

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public String getData(@RequestParam(value = "api_key", defaultValue = "QPayNCt8xoMomlYfVdySXOEGxAxXfiV2") String apiKey,
                      @RequestParam(value = "q", defaultValue = "cheeseburgers") String q,
                      @RequestParam(value = "limit", defaultValue = "5") String limit);
```

Comment: Ok. I did the change :@FeignClient(url="http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs", name="GIPHY-CLIENT")
public interface GipherSearch {
 @GetMapping("/search?api_key=QPayNCt8xoMomlYfVdySXOEGxAxXfiV2&q=cheeseburgers&limit=5")
  public List<DataModel> getData(@PathVariable("api_key") String api_key,
                          @PathVariable("q") String searchValue,
                          @PathVariable("limit") int limit);

Comment: But when I called the feign client  I need to call like that right.@GetMapping("/findAllGipher/{api_key}/{q}/{limit}")
    public List<DataModel> getAllGipher(@PathVariable("api_key") String api_key,
            @PathVariable("q") String searchValue,
            @PathVariable("limit") int limit){
     return gipherSearch.getData( api_key,searchValue,limit);
     
    }

Comment: If you want to do this `/{api_key}/{q}/{limit}` ok but it is not necessary since you can pass values as null, and `default values` will be those you added.

Comment: I have a questions here . I need to call the interface method from the controller class. So in that case it will ask some parameter in the controller when calling the inter face method. What value I will pass there and the 'q' parameter value is the search param value and it was not fixed.

Comment: Okay, no problem what you want to do, what error did you get? it is the same? if it is the same then try to check all fields and/or object JSON which is sent from `/api.giphy.com/v1/gifs`  because you got that exception for it.

Comment: I want to call third party URL with feign client.It has request param like API_KEY and searchString value.